# Linking integer id with text in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can connect to a database in Postgres.

It has a table called **country** with 201 rows. This consists of two fields: **country_id** (integer) and **country_name** (text).

It has another table called **school** with 2233 rows. It consists of a field called **country** (integer). This field lists integers that each represent one of the 201 **country_id** from the **country** table.

If I do a command like:

```
SELECT country from school limit 10;
```

I can get the first 10 **country_id**'s. Is it possible for me to easily translate these 10 **country_id**'s into their **country_name**'s using the country table?

Comment: That's exactly the kind of problems `JOIN` is meant for - quick intro can be found in the Postgres docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-join.html) - one of the samples is an almost verbatim solution to this question...

Comment: Note that `limit 10` doesn't guarantee which 10 you get. If you want the "first" 10 you need an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join to achieve this..

I wrote the query for MYSQL

```
create table country
(id numeric,
 c_name varchar(20));

 insert into country values(1,'America');
 insert into country values(2,'India');
 insert into country values(3,'Britain');
 insert into country values(4,'Greece');
 insert into country values(5,'China');

 create table School
(school_name varchar(20),
 country_id Numeric);

 Insert into school values ('A',2);
 Insert into school values ('B',4);
 Insert into school values ('c',5);
 Insert into school values ('D',4);



 Select c_name 
from country c
join School s
on c.id = s.country_id
Order by c_name
Limit 2

c_name
China
Greece
```

If you only want to show the country name once you can use `Distinct`

Also if you are LIMIT you should do a `orderby` else it will give different result on each time..